# When exactly are PHP-MySQL variable assignments made?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, insert

[Status: learner] 
Using checkboxes, the user selects rows from a displayed HTML table.  I then want to insert the date and the unique row id ("select_id") of the selected ('ticked') rows into a different table.  Maybe I'm off-base, but it seems to me that the first block of code **does not work**.  The second block of code **does work**.  If I'm correct, it appears that it matters where the $SQL statement is made.  WHY?  I mean, no variable assignments are made until the $sql is called by the mysql_query() function, right?

(...If I'm wrong, nevermind, it is just a normal evening at home.)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sap_id_select (  select_date
                                   , select_id )
        VALUES (  CURRENT_DATE ()
                , '{$cSelected_id}' ) 
       " ;

if ( isset ( $_POST [ checkbox] ) ) 
   { 
      foreach ( $_POST [ checkbox ] as $cSelected_id )
         {
            mysql_query ( $sql ) or ( "Error: " . mysql_error () ) ;
         }
   }
```

================================

```
 if ( isset ( $_POST [ checkbox] ) ) 
    { 
       foreach ( $_POST [ checkbox ] as $cSelected_id )
          {
             $sql = "INSERT INTO sap_id_select (  select_date
                                                , select_id )
                     VALUES (  CURRENT_DATE ()
                             , '{$cSelected_id}' ) 
                    " ;

             mysql_query ( $sql ) or ( "Error: " . mysql_error () ) ;
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example one, the query is assuming the existence of a variable, which isn't there. If you want, you could [parameterize the query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), and add the values within the `foreach`, but you cannot do it as you're attempting in example 1.

**Example:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sap_id_select(select_id) VALUES('%s')";

if (isset($_POST["checkbox"])) {
  foreach ($_POST["checkbox"] as $cSelected_id) {
    mysql_query ( sprintf($sql, $cSelected_id) ) or ("Error: ".mysql_error());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Johathan.  If you will indulge me, why isn't the $sql statement a "bunch of text" prior to its usage by the mysql_query() function?  [IOW, if I understand you correctly, the {$cSelected_id} assignment is made as soon as the $sql statement is parsed, and does NOT wait until it is put into action by mysql_query().]

Comment: I believe that is the case, dave.